# How to login to Azure Active Directory single sign-on (SSO) integration with Google Cloud (G Suite) Connector using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, azure-active-directory, google-signin, stress-testing

I want to login to my application using **JMeter** to perform Stress Testing.

But in my application, we have authentication of **Azure Active Directory single sign-on (SSO)** along with Google.

Can anyone help me, **How to do login to the application using JMeter**

Comment: Did you read about manual authorization setup with OAuth endpoint? You should move that way. Here is an example of an answer for a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41820447/1595293