# JMeter OAuth2.0 Auth0 access token

Tags: oauth-2.0, jmeter

How to generate OAuth2.0 access tokens in Jmeter.?

I'm able to get the setup for Postman using OAuth2.0. However, when I want to test these and develop script in JMeter, I am unable to get through it.
[image]

This postman setup doesnt ask for client_secretKey only required client_Id, instead it pops up a window where I enter the username and password and then it is redirected/called back to my application URL.
When I looked into the URL, it has the following parameters

```
https://product.auth0.com/authorize?
redirect_uri=abc.com
client_id=XXX
errorPath=%2Ferror
scope=openid%20profile%20email%20offline_access
response_type=code
response_mode=query
state=dynamicvalue1
nonce=dynamicvalue2
code_challenge=dynamicvalue3
code_challenge_method=S256
auth0Client=staticvalue HTTP/1.1
```

I know client_secretKey, now I am wondering if I can able to get to the authorisation/authentication of the application by using the client ID, secretKey grant type etc?

Please suggest on ways I can connect to and access the application.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do a OAuth 2.0 authentication in JMeter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41818784/how-to-do-a-oauth-2-0-authentication-in-jmeter)

Comment: Yes, I did try it but in JMeter, I get the Invalid JSON response. I have made couple of trials with the parameters and URL, but wasn't giving proper response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postman is a browser plugin, JMeter is not a browser hence it cannot "pop up w window"

The easiest way of capturing the network requests from Posman in JMeter is  just recording it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder.](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)

1. [Start JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
2. [Import JMeter's certificate into Postman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/certificates/)

   [image]
3. [Configure Postman to use JMeter as the proxy](https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/proxy/)

   [image]
4. Run your request in Postman.
5. JMeter should generate proper [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) and you should be able to replay the request.
6. Identify the dynamic parameters and perform their [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/correlation-in-jmeter)
7. You should be able to replay the authorization flow using JMeter now.

Comment: Thanks again @Dmitri for your valuable inputs. I have used POSTMAN as per your suggestion and also the CHrome network tab to get through the list of HTTP requests and I am able to successfully recreate the Oauth2.0 flow for the application.