# Keycloak monolithic app load testing using jmeter

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, keycloak, load-testing

I was Looking for a way to load test my monolithic application using jmeter , However i was unable to do using the Jmeter as it used Keycloak based authentication and was not sure how to handle this using jmeter

Can someone please suggest how to do this in Jmeter or any other tool available to complete this activity

Tried recording scripts using blazemeter plugin but it failed as it was not getting logged in

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do a OAuth 2.0 authentication in JMeter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41818784/how-to-do-a-oauth-2-0-authentication-in-jmeter)

Answer (score 0):

"Keycloak based authentication" can be one of the following:

- [OAuth 2.0](https://oauth.net/2/)
- [SAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language)
- [OpenID Connect](https://openid.net/developers/how-connect-works/)

so you need to identify which protocol is being used and look for JMeter-specific instructions for bypassing authentication/authorization challenge for this protocol in your JMeter test.

If you're looking for a general piece of advice it would be one word: [**correlation**](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start):

1. Record your test using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
2. Identify dynamic values
3. Extract them from previous responses using suitable JMeter [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and replace recorded values with the relevant JMeter Variables
4. That would be it

Here is an example of correlating dynamic values in Keycloak-protected application using [Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-boundary-extractor):

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have sent state and nonce parameter what are these ?

Comment: My application uses open id  auth

Comment: Nice animation demo but too fast animation GIF, can you make explain step by step?